# Excel VBA getElementsByTagName - Runtime error - 424

Tags: vba, excel, getelementsbytagname

I'm using the following references: Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library, Microsoft Internet Controls.

I've singled out the line below where I'm running into this error. I've tried using innerText and textContent without any success.

I've also tried the following this methodoly: http://automatetheweb.net/vba-getelementsbytagname-method/ without any success as I run into a runtime error 70.

I've tried to getElementsByClassName.getElementsByTagName without any success.

I've tried posting this question in Microsoft Community answers but I've had very little success using that site in general in the past.

```
Sub ZipCodeRetrieve()

Dim ZipCodeRange As Range
Dim PopDensity As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim PopChange As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim IE As Object
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

'Creates ie instance
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ZipCodes")
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Navigate "http://mcdc.missouri.edu/websas/caps10c.html"
IE.Visible = True

Set ZipCodeRange = Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Debug.Print ZipCodeRange.Address

For Each cell In ZipCodeRange

    'allows ie to load before proceeding
    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'looks for search box in Missouri.edu and inputs zipcode
    IE.document.all("latitude").Value = cell.Value
    'radius is constant
    IE.document.all("radii").Value = 75
    'clicks enter
    IE.document.forms(0).submit

    'allows ie to load before proceeding
    Do While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'preps ie for data collection
    Set HTMLdoc = IE.document
```

THIS IS WERE I'M GETTING THE ERROR

```
 Set PopDensity = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("b").Item(18).innerText


    Set PopChange = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("b").Item(10).textContent

    Debug.Print PopDensity.Value
    Debug.Print PopChange.Value

Next cell

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set PopDensity = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("b").Item(18).innerText
```

You've declared `PopDensity` as `IHTMLElementCollection` but here you're assigning a value from `innerText`, which as the method name suggests return text, not a collection.

Try this:

```
Dim PopDensity 'As String 'or leave as variant
PopDensity = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("b").Item(18).innerText
```

Comment: That did exactly what I needed it to do. I still don't understand why everyone suggests I use IHTMLElementCollection. Most of the examples using getElementsByTagName use this and they use innerText function as well. In any case, Thank you!

Comment: IHTMLElementCollection is what you get from `getElementsByTagName`, so if you stopped there then it would work, but you're tagging on `Item()` (which returns only a single element) and then `innerText` (which returns text)

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, IHTMLElementCollection would return all "b"s instead of just a single one?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("b")` *returns* all "b" elements, and a reference to that returned collection can be assigned to a variable of type `IHTMLElementCollection`